# jQuery animate queue option is not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I trying to create a jQuery animation and pass in queue:true as an option. but it is not working and both animations occur at same time.

i have 2 jQuery animations within an anonymous function and am trying to pass in the option for queue:true but it is not working. They are both running at the same time.

Below is the code. i’ve removed some of the animated elements for easier reading.

```
jQuery('#info-icon').clickToggle(
    function() {   
     console.log('clicked 1');
     jQuery('.more-info-icon').animate({top:"280", 'font-size':"14px", width:"30px", height:"30px"}, { duration:1000, queue: true });
     jQuery('.info-text-wrapper').animate({opacity:1}, {duration:1000, queue: true });
},
    function() {
      console.log('clicked 2');
      jQuery('.info-text-wrapper').animate({opacity:0}, {duration:1000, queue: true });
      jQuery('.more-info-icon').animate({top:"50%", 'font-size':"70px", width:"100px", height:"100px"},{duration:1000, queue: true });
});
```

The I ‘info’ is suppose to shrink and move to the bottom of the container, after which the text fades in. and then the toggle should be the reverse. I’ve included a link here.

http://hearnowmusic.net/anim_queue/index.html

note: these animations occur within a custom toggle function which is not included on this page.

any help would be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery animation queue only queues animations done on the *same element*. In your code you are animating two separate elements so they both fire immediately. What you can do instead is use the 'complete' callback option to trigger the second animation after the first one.

```
function() {
  console.log('clicked 1');
  jQuery('.more-info-icon').animate(
    {top:"280", 'font-size':"14px", width:"30px", height:"30px"},
    {
      duration:1000,
      complete: function(){
        jQuery('.info-text-wrapper').animate({opacity:1}, {duration:1000});
      } 
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: thank you, that works. though it doesn't say what is wrong w/ my code, why it isn't working